# Homotopic Manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $\Sigma_{g}^{*}$ be a punctured Surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ of genus g(A torus with g holes and without a point). My conjecture is that this manifold is not homotopic to $\mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash$ {$p_{1},p_{2},\cdots p_{2g}$}. I've tried proving that they have different De Rham Cohomology, but Mayers Vietoris sequence gives  $H^{1}_{dR}(\Sigma_{g}^{*})\equiv H^{1}_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^{2}\backslash$ {$p_{1},p_{2},\cdots p_{2g}$}$\cong \mathbb{R}^{2g}$ (the others are trivially equal).

So now I'm in doubt. Are they homotopic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are homotopic since they are deformation  retract to the bouquet of $2g$-circles. You can represent the surface by identify the boundary of a $4g$-gon without a point in the midlle, it retracts to quotient of  the boundary  which is a bouquet of $2g$-circles.

Comment: I only kew that you can represent a suface of genus g with a 4g-gon. I think that the idea is the same, but tell me, how do you see that the k-punctured plane is a bouquet of 2g circles?